# Weak convergence of an integral of an exponential of a Wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes

EDIT: corrected the problem thesis.

Suppose $(W_s)_{s \geq 0}$ is a Wiener process. Define
$$
V_t := \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\log \left[\int_{0}^{t}\exp(W_s)ds\right]
$$
Show that
$$
V_t \xrightarrow{t \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{s \in[0, 1]}W_s
$$
in distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
V_t := \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\int_{0}^{t}\exp(W_s)ds
= \sqrt{t} \int_{0}^{1} \exp(W_{tu}) du
$$

The process $(X^{[t]}_s)_{s\ge 0}$ defined by
$$
X^{[t]}_s =  \frac 1{\sqrt t} W_{ts}
$$is a Brownian motion for each $t$, and

\begin{align}
V_t &= \sqrt{t} \int_{0}^{1} \exp(\sqrt t X^{[t]}_u) du\\
&\overset{(dist.)}= \sqrt{t} \int_{0}^{1} \exp(\sqrt t W_u) du\\
\end{align}

Now I am not convinced that the result holds, but you have:
$$
\left(\frac{V_t}{\sqrt t}\right)^{\frac 1{\sqrt t}} \overset{(dist.)}=
\left(\int_{0}^{1} \exp(\sqrt t W_u) du\right)^{\frac 1{\sqrt t}} 
\to \sup_{0\le u \le 1} \exp W_u
$$

---

With the second version:
$$V_t=\frac 1 {\sqrt t} \log ∫_0^t \exp W_s ds
=\log \left[ ∫_0^t \exp W_s ds\right] ^{ \frac 1 {\sqrt t} }
\\\to \log \sup_{0\le u\le 1} \exp \exp W_u
= \sup_{0\le u\le 1}W_u
$$

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right that the problem's thesis is not true. Moreover, from your reasoning we can imply that $V_t$ does not converge weakly to any probability distribution.

Comment: OK, I received a corrected version of the problem - $V_t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \log \left[ \int_{0}^{t} \exp(W_s)ds \right]$ and the thesis stays as it was.

Comment: @tosi3k  can you take it from here?